# How to read a JSON retrieved from an API and save it into a CSV file?

Tags: python, json, csv

I am using a weather API that responses with a JSON file. Here is a sample of the returned readings:

```
{
  'data': {
    'request': [{
      'type': 'City',
      'query': 'Karachi, Pakistan'
    }],
    'weather': [{
      'date': '2019-03-10',
      'astronomy': [{
        'sunrise': '06:46 AM',
        'sunset': '06:38 PM',
        'moonrise': '09:04 AM',
        'moonset': '09:53 PM',
        'moon_phase': 'Waxing Crescent',
        'moon_illumination': '24'
      }],
      'maxtempC': '27',
      'maxtempF': '80',
      'mintempC': '22',
      'mintempF': '72',
      'totalSnow_cm': '0.0',
      'sunHour': '11.6',
      'uvIndex': '7',
      'hourly': [{
        'time': '24',
        'tempC': '27',
        'tempF': '80',
        'windspeedMiles': '10',
        'windspeedKmph': '16',
        'winddirDegree': '234',
        'winddir16Point': 'SW',
        'weatherCode': '116',
        'weatherIconUrl': [{
          'value': 'http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png'
        }],
        'weatherDesc': [{
          'value': 'Partly cloudy'
        }],
        'precipMM': '0.0',
        'humidity': '57',
        'visibility': '10',
        'pressure': '1012',
        'cloudcover': '13',
        'HeatIndexC': '25',
        'HeatIndexF': '78',
        'DewPointC': '15',
        'DewPointF': '59',
        'WindChillC': '24',
        'WindChillF': '75',
        'WindGustMiles': '12',
        'WindGustKmph': '19',
        'FeelsLikeC': '25',
        'FeelsLikeF': '78',
        'uvIndex': '0'
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

I used the following Python code in my attempt to reading the data stored in JSON file:

```
import simplejson as json 
data_file = open("new.json", "r") 
values = json.load(data_file)
```

But this outputs with an error as follows:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error
```

I am also wondering how I can save the result in a structured format in a CSV file using Python.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: It's unclear what the csv file must look like in the end

Answer (score -1):

As stated below by Rami, the simplest way to do this would to use pandas to either a) `.read_json()`, or to use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`. however the issue with this particular case is you have nested dictionary/json. What do I mean it's nested? Well, if you were to simply put this into a dataframe, you'd have this:

```
print (df)
                                          request                                            weather
0  {'type': 'City', 'query': 'Karachi, Pakistan'}  {'date': '2019-03-10', 'astronomy': [{'sunrise...
```

Which is fine if that's what you want. However, I am assuming you'd like all the data/instance flattened into a singe row.

So you'll need to either use `json_normalize` to unravel it (which is possible, but you'd need to be certain the json file follows the same format/keys throughout. And you'd still need to pull out each of the dictionaries within the list, within the dictionaries. Other option is use some function to flatten out the nested json. Then from there you can simply write to file:

I choose to flatten it using a function, then construct the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import re
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


data = {'data': {'request': [{'type': 'City', 'query': 'Karachi, Pakistan'}], 'weather': [{'date': '2019-03-10', 'astronomy': [{'sunrise': '06:46 AM', 'sunset': '06:38 PM', 'moonrise': '09:04 AM', 'moonset': '09:53 PM', 'moon_phase': 'Waxing Crescent', 'moon_illumination': '24'}], 'maxtempC': '27', 'maxtempF': '80', 'mintempC': '22', 'mintempF': '72', 'totalSnow_cm': '0.0', 'sunHour': '11.6', 'uvIndex': '7', 'hourly': [{'time': '24', 'tempC': '27', 'tempF': '80', 'windspeedMiles': '10', 'windspeedKmph': '16', 'winddirDegree': '234', 'winddir16Point': 'SW', 'weatherCode': '116', 'weatherIconUrl': [{'value': 'http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png'}], 'weatherDesc': [{'value': 'Partly cloudy'}], 'precipMM': '0.0', 'humidity': '57', 'visibility': '10', 'pressure': '1012', 'cloudcover': '13', 'HeatIndexC': '25', 'HeatIndexF': '78', 'DewPointC': '15', 'DewPointF': '59', 'WindChillC': '24', 'WindChillF': '75', 'WindGustMiles': '12', 'WindGustKmph': '19', 'FeelsLikeC': '25', 'FeelsLikeF': '78', 'uvIndex': '0'}]}]}}

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out


flat = flatten_json(data['data'])


results = pd.DataFrame()
special_cols = []

columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
    try:
        row_idx = re.findall(r'\_(\d+)\_', item )[0]
    except:
        special_cols.append(item)
        continue
    column = re.findall(r'\_\d+\_(.*)', item )[0]
    column = column.replace('_', '')

    row_idx = int(row_idx)
    value = flat[item]

    results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

for item in special_cols:
    results[item] = flat[item]

results.to_csv('path/filename.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
   type              query        date astronomy0sunrise astronomy0sunset astronomy0moonrise astronomy0moonset astronomy0moonphase astronomy0moonillumination maxtempC maxtempF mintempC mintempF totalSnowcm sunHour uvIndex hourly0time hourly0tempC hourly0tempF hourly0windspeedMiles hourly0windspeedKmph hourly0winddirDegree hourly0winddir16Point hourly0weatherCode                        hourly0weatherIconUrl0value hourly0weatherDesc0value hourly0precipMM hourly0humidity hourly0visibility hourly0pressure hourly0cloudcover hourly0HeatIndexC hourly0HeatIndexF hourly0DewPointC hourly0DewPointF hourly0WindChillC hourly0WindChillF hourly0WindGustMiles hourly0WindGustKmph hourly0FeelsLikeC hourly0FeelsLikeF hourly0uvIndex
0  City  Karachi, Pakistan  2019-03-10          06:46 AM         06:38 PM           09:04 AM          09:53 PM     Waxing Crescent                         24       27       80       22       72         0.0    11.6       7          24           27           80                    10                   16                  234                    SW                116  http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymb...            Partly cloudy             0.0              57                10            1012                13                25                78               15               59                24                75                   12                  19                25                78              0
```

Comment: i use this code it work for single row but when i add more than one row like 
    data = []
data1 =[]
  not working

Comment: I can only work with what you provide. Given that you are receiving this from an api, I can only assume the data returned will be  in this format. So are YOU adding more rows of `data = []` and `data1 = []`, or is the API returning that to you? And what does that even look like? If it's the API, then you need to provide that as your sample/example data in your question. Also, as hiro protagonist pointed out, you may want to read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Actualy API return 5 years weather data similar to as i mentioned which is single day data. i need to store in Csv file. Sorry for wrongly ask the question which cause confusion.

Comment: It’s not a wrongly asked question, people want to help. you just need to provide as much detail as needed to produce your desired output (it also helps to give an example of what sort of output you’re trying to achieve). If you’re saying it works with what you provided, but then doesn’t work with what you have, there’s not much more anyone can do. I can only produce an output with what you provided as I don’t know what your full data looks like. Is it possible to share the json file?

Comment: https://www.zomfy.com/WMBN63c i have attached the json file in this link

Comment: "Upload not found" response to link